# Change Connection String at Login Depending on business id

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am trying to find the best way to approach the following:

I have an application website that I want to use for all businesses (ASP.NET/C#). However, depending on the business name at login, I want to switch databases. In other words, each business has its own MySQL database, exactly the same structure and procedures so it won't conflict with the front-end code. What would be the best way to accomplish this? I though about adding different connection string at the web.config and depending on the business id, use one or the other. However, I do not want to end up with tens of connection strings in the web.config. Must be another way more efficient. I am also concern about security, so if I am business ABC, I want to make sure I will always see the ABC database only. Any feedback will be greatly appreciate it.

Below is my sample global login using a login database:

```
protected void GlobalLogin(string email, string password)
        {
            int salt = email.Trim().Length;
            string hashedPassword;
            Passwords obj = new Passwords(password, salt);
            hashedPassword = obj.ComputeSaltedHash();
            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("sp...", connection))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = email;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = hashedPassword;
                    connection.Open();
                    MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        dr.Read();
                        {
                          ... set session and go to the homepage
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh well... You definitely need a storage for connection strings. Config file is one of the options. You can also create a single database with a single table that holds the connection strings for each business. Your web.config file needs to have the connection string to this centralized DB (which you should encrypt its data using SQL server's encryption). When user identifies the target business (somehow..perhaps from login page), you need to connect to the centralized DB, get the connection string for the user's business and set your connection string dynamically.

For performance reasons, you may cache the connection strings in memory, so you don't have to constantly hit the centralized DB.

Comment: Thanks a lot Feryal for your help. I am creating a centralized DB that will hold the connection string but I am using MySQL and not SQL Server. At the login page is when I need to switch databases, once the user is authenticated and we know what business is coming from. I will update my question shortly with the centralized DB.

Comment: I have never used MySql, but I found some links about how to encrypt a column in MySQL, so you still can encrypt your connection strings. It is important that you do not store them in plain text, because if anyone gets access to that table, he/she will have the key to the kingdom.

Comment: If you are thinking about having 3 fields in the login page (business ID, user name and password), I have to tell you that in one of my previous lives (jobs), we were doing the same thing and our clients didn't like that. More fields to enter means more chances to enter wrong data and not getting in. It can get even more complicated if you think about the password reset (forgot password) feature...user may forget the business Id too.

Comment: Understand, the thing is that I have multiple businesses and multiple databases, I still need a single login/password for each business that will then get the right database file. I am reading about encrypting DB in MySQL but so far it looks it may be more secure to have an encrypted db.config file that will host multiple connection strings and have it appended to the web.config file. Once the business successfully authenticates then the program should call the correct connection string